# ThemeKey: Use main theme for Node/edit and user/edit

Tags: theme-negotiation

By default, Drupal uses the "main theme" for the main site, and the "admin theme" for the admin pages.

I want to use my "main theme" for the `user/edit` pages and `node/edit` & `node/add` pages of the "journal" content type only.
For all other administration pages (including the `node/edit` & `node/add` pages of other content types) , I want to use the "admin theme".

How can I do this? In Theme Key there doesn't seem to be options to select `node/edit` & node add pages of a particular content type (or options to select `user/edit` pages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will need to create a hierarchical set up:

[image]

In this example set up, it checks for user:1 (admin), that the node type (content type) is article, and that the path meets the relevant criteria. You will need to adjust accordingly. Simply drag and drop the sub-elements into place.

Comment: Do I disable the admin theme at admin/appearance? 

If I do, then how do I get the admin theme (Seven) to apply to the admin pages (with the exception of journal and users)?

If I do not turn it off, then do I uncheck the box for "Use the administration theme when editing or creating content". 

How do I get theme key to target the user pages? I have tried using wildcard path user/# but it doesn't seem to work. 

Also, is `path_is_admin = True` used for the admin pages? It seems to target all admin sections including `user/edit` and `node/edit`, which doesn't have "admin" in the path.

Comment: thats a lot of questions... you may need to install Themekey Comptability Module and manually override the admin users themeìng - never had a reason to do it, so I don`t know the exact settings you will need, you need to play around with it. For user pages, it is the same process, only with the relevant url(s)